# I recovered a deleted Ubuntu partition on dual-boot but I am having problem with booting through grub. How can I go about this?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, boot-partition

I am using a Dual boot (Windows and Ubuntu). But, I mistakenly deleted a particular partition (Ubuntu 22.4.1), I quickly recovered a partition using some recovery tools I saw online.

The problem now is , when logging into the Ubuntu , I am met with Grub> ;

What I did. I “ls” to check folders , and set the root ,

```
grub > set root=(hd0,msdos2)
grub > set prefix=(hd0,msdos2)/boot/grub
grub > insmod normal
grub > normal
```

But when I reboot , nothing happens. I still meet grub>. I am scared to do anything other thing so that I don’t miss a chance to get back to the original state on my Ubuntu.

I will welcome any helpful solutions to this. Thank you.

Comment: It reads like you don't want the Ubuntu partition at all, thus the fastest fix is to boot Windows recovery media (*I gather that's what you want to keep*) and make windows own the boot process.  This should have been done before you deleted the Ubuntu partition (windows has a command for this, command varies on version of windows), but the tool exists on windows recovery media too meaning you can do it if forgotten.   FYI: *It reads like your recovery was not very successful, as if it was you'd not have this issue*

Comment: @guiverc, Of course, I want the Ubuntu. But I recovered the Ubuntu partition through windows. Because I deleted a Volume assigned to the Ubuntu. So, I had to quickly recovered the Volume partition. I tried to boot to Ubuntu but I can’t boot in. This is the problem. I used this recovery tool on Windows. I recovered it back on the partition. It’s a dual partition. How can I get back on Ubuntu?

Comment: @guiverc I just tried this answer on link you shared but it didn’t help. Whelp

Comment: You've not been specific about what Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS system you're talking about, is it a Server system? a Desktop system?   If it was me (*and it was a Desktop system*), and I had mistakenly deleted & then recovered data, I'd boot a *live* system and explore what was recovered & then re-install.  You can re-install a Ubuntu Desktop system without loss of data, and have the *manually installed* packages (ie. those you added after install) auto-reinstalled (*if from Ubuntu repositories & not third party&), as this would mean you have a *new* (even if '*unclean*') system installed.

Comment: I also don't know what partition you did delete, if you're asking about uEFI or a BIOS/legacy system.. thus I'm missing a lot of detail, which makes me prefer the idea of non-destructive re-install too. However that's just what I'd do, in your case, I'd wait for other advice from other users of this site too (who may have other questions & differing opinions on how they'd resolve the issue).  My approach also assumes Desktop, you maybe asking about Server or something else too.